# VS keeps copying over files after a compile with a target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2017, target

I want to clean a directory and copy over some files into it for each compilation. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order), I can use [AfterTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order#beforetargets-and-aftertargets) to do that.

I've added the following to the bottom of my CSPROJ file.

```
<Target Name="Web" AfterTargets="Compile">
  <Exec Command="del .\wwwroot\* /F /Q /S" />
  <Exec Command="xcopy ..\Web\dist\* .\wwwroot /I /S /Y" />
</Target>
```

It kind of works, because after I've run a build, the target directory is emptied then repopulated by the new version of files from the source.

However, that process keeps on - the removal and re-copy is repeated on and on continuously until I close VS.

What am I doing wrong in the target implementation? How do I stop the process and make it only execute once?

Comment: I've had this issue with a post-build event too. I'm suspecting a bug in VS. Would be very interested if someone solves this.

Comment: @SteveJ How did you resolve it? I've never found docs on what other stages than *Compile* and *Link* are there so I couldn't try them out. I'm a bit unclear if/how using *BeforeTarget* would affect the situation and I sense that due to my ignorance, I'd be wasting the computer power by trial-and-horror.

Comment: I never resolved it I'm afraid - had to abandon what I was trying to do.